# Disable Mouse Function Python Code problem

Tags: python, pyhook

Using the following code to disable my mouse and keyboard for 10 seconds.  I'm still able to move my mouse and keyboard while the code is running.  also I want to call this function from another script in python but I'm not able to.  Any suggestions?

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, time

start = time.time()
time.perf_counter
elapsed = 0

def windoow(event):
    global elapsed
    if elapsed < 10:
       elapsed = time.time() - start
       time.sleep(1)
       return False

    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = windoow
hm.KeyAll = windoow
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: To call it from another python file, you need to put all of the code inside a function. When you import a file in python, it 'runs' it, which will create the function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, just two lines of programming solved the problem:

```py
from ctypes import *

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(True) #enable block

#or 

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(False) #disable block
```

Comment: You can put import to start of the code and the other lines, you can put them where you want